# (Unreal Engine 4.27.2) Dedicated Server not working with Steam API

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, steamworks-api, unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

After I updated the ini file to activate the Steam Subsystem plugin, the dedicated server is unable to host the map level, and closes the connection and then creates an infinite loop of failed attempts. But on the client it works perfectly, I can even open the steam panel inside the standalone game.

Dedicated Server Log:

```
[2022.12.04-01.11.01:940][  2]LogModuleManager: Warning: ModuleManager: Unable to load module 'SocketsSTEAM'  - 0 instances of that module name found.
[2022.12.04-01.11.01:940][  2]LogSockets: Warning: Unable to load SocketSubsystem module STEAM
[2022.12.04-01.11.01:940][  2]LogNet: ReplicationDriverClass is null! Not using ReplicationDriver.
[2022.12.04-01.11.01:940][  2]LogNetCore: DDoS detection status: detection enabled: 0 analytics enabled: 0
[2022.12.04-01.11.01:941][  2]LogSockets: Warning: SteamSockets: Cannot get information on an invalid socket handle, returning null
[2022.12.04-01.11.01:941][  2]LogNet: Warning: Could not create socket for bind address ::, got error SteamSockets: setsockopt SO_BROADCAST failed (0)
[2022.12.04-01.11.01:941][  2]LogNet: Warning: Encountered an error while creating sockets for the bind addresses.
[2022.12.04-01.11.01:941][  2]LogNet: Warning: Failed to init net driver ListenURL: /Game/ThirdPersonBP/Maps/ThirdPersonExampleMap500?closed:
[2022.12.04-01.11.01:941][  2]LogNet: Error: UEngine::BroadcastNetworkFailure: FailureType = NetDriverListenFailure, ErrorString = , Driver = GameNetDriver IpNetDriver_3
[2022.12.04-01.11.01:941][  2]LogNet: Server_Error: Net Driver Listen Failure
[2022.12.04-01.11.01:941][  2]LogWorld: Failed to listen:
[2022.12.04-01.11.01:941][  2]LogNet: DestroyNamedNetDriver IpNetDriver_3 [GameNetDriver]
[2022.12.04-01.11.01:941][  2]LogNet: Error: LoadMap: failed to Listen(/Game/ThirdPersonBP/Maps/ThirdPersonExampleMap500?closed)
[2022.12.04-01.11.01:942][  2]LogSkeletalMesh: USkeletalMeshComponent::InitArticulated : Could not find root physics body: '/Game/ThirdPersonBP/Maps/ThirdPersonExampleMap500.ThirdPersonExampleMap500:PersistentLevel.SK_Mannequin_Arms_2.SkeletalMeshComponent0'
```

start bat:

```
"C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.27\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor.exe" "D:\MyProject\MyProject.uproject" ThirdPersonExampleMap500 -server -steam -log
exit
```

Even passing the "-nosteam" parameter, the dedicated server remains incommunicable as long as Steam is open.

STEAM SDK V1.51

[UE4_Wiki](https://michaeljcole.github.io/wiki.unrealengine.com/Steam,_Using_the_Steam_SDK_During_Development/)

I've followed all these steps beyond activating the plugin to install the Steam SDK, but something seems to be missing to make it work in multiplayer.